# why can't access the static files?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm work in .net core web api. When I try to access the usersImages folder who is inside wwwroot I got error 404.
[image]

In startup class I use:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
      {
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
              app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          }
          app.UseStaticFiles();
          app.UseCors(options =>
          {
              options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyHeader();
          });        
          app.UseAuthentication();
          app.UseMvc();
      }
```

Comment: As you can see, the server is looking in a different place for your files. Could you show the code that tries to load that image?

Comment: I try to load from angular app :
`<img class="img-responsive" src="/usersImages/{{userApi.user.imageUrl}}"/>`

Comment: Can you show us the content of `<system.webServer>` section from your configuration file?

Comment: {
  "AppSettings": {
    "Quiz_coDbConnection": "This is connection string;",
    "Secret": "THIS CAN BE ANYTHING"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Comment: Can you share the startup class in your question? UseStaticFiles is a middleware, and Asp.Net Core middlewares are executed in a pipeline. Maybe you put it in the wrong sequence.

Comment: @LuttiCoelho That's probably the reason.

Comment: I share my Configure method  in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Configure method looks right, but I just realize that your image url looks wrong.

You are requesting your image under the url: `localhost:63040/api/userImages/userid.jpg`

I believe you don't have a api folder under your `wwwroot` folder. Imagine that your images are under `wwwroot` > `userImages` > `userid.jpg`. So you url should be: `localhost:63040/userImages/userid.jpg`

Comment: Thank you @Lutti Coelho